# Are WAN and "backbone" same?

Tags: networking, wan

As a non-network engineer, I came across the term "backbone". The situation only requires a casual understanding of it, or even fine without it, but I was interested to do a light research.

As I understand, it seems to mean "what connects LANs".

And WAN, as I understand, is "what's outside of LAN; beyond gateway".
Some describe WAN as "*geographically* remote networks" or something and that confuses me as well. I mean, what constittutes as *geographically remote*? Is it 100m? Is it 10km? 1000km? Or perhaps it meant "distinct LANs", in which case, it's the same thing as "backbone".

Q) Are WAN and backbone same?

Also in the way, if any of my understanding is incorrect or lacks nuance, please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, *LAN* and *WAN* stood for vastly different technologies. Since nearly anything nowadays uses former LAN technology (Ethernet), that distinction has all but vanished.

Today, the terms depend largely on context. *WAN* can refer to the open Internet, a larger interconnection or central area, or simply very long links (many kilometers) while *LAN* is mostly used for in-building or on-premises networking.

Often *WAN* is also used for an open security zone using public addressing or allowing unfiltered traffic. Paradoxically, such a WAN zone may sometimes just span a few meters geographically.

A *backbone* is the center structure in a (larger) network that interconnects all parts of that network. It needs to be highly resilient and very fast. *Backbone* may also be used for the central OSPF area 0 or in a similar context.

Accordingly, *WAN* and *backbone* can sometimes mean the same or may refer to entirely different things.

Answer (score 2):

Backbone is a general term that can only be understood in context. So in some cases a *backbone* could be a WAN, but in other cases, no.

Backbone refers more to the topological structure, where it provides a central connection to various other things.

Comment: ospf backbone area(Area 0)  could be WAN?

Comment: @AlokMaity It could be, but not necessarily. Area 0 is the backbone *for OSPF* but that may differ from your overall network topology.

Comment: We call area 0 the backbone because it is the central area that connects all the other areas together.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, most of actual backbones are WANs, but not all WANs are backbones, WANs are wide networks, and those include in most of the cases, to users, while backbones networks are the core of a network, and those includes transmission devices, not access or user devices, normally they connect various networks, and users cant directly acces those. They start, most of times, in connections at layer 3 switchs and routers

Comment: I have to disagree.  The term *backbone* can be used in different contexts, and WANs don't have to be part of it. I can have a *backbone* network tying the floors of my building together, or the racks in my data center, but no one would call that a WAN.  Then there's the common use of *backbone* to describe OSPF area 0.

Comment: thinking straight, yes you are right, let me rephrase this of a wide quantity of actual backbones are WANs